# How could I remove the ::after effect using JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to remove the `::after` effect after a function is completed using JS.

Here is the code:

```js
let text = 'Stack Overflow is a question and answer website for professional and enthusiast programmers. It is the flagship site of the Stack Exchange Network,[4][5][6] created in 2008 by Jeff Atwood and Joel Spolsky'
let interval;
let i = 0;
interval = setInterval(function() {
  if (i < text.length) {
    document.querySelector('div').textContent += text.charAt(i)
  } else {
    window.clearInterval(interval)
  }
  i++
}, 20)
```

```css
div::after {
  content: '|'
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

I just wonder if there is a way that I could remove the "|" (`::after` effect) after the `interval` finished.

Thanks for any responds!

Comment: @kmoser The duplicate question is about `:active` pseudo-class, not `::after` pseudo-element. Can you use the same solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a class to your definition, you can switch this one and off

div.foo::after{
content:'|'
}

```
setInterval(function(){
                if(i<text.length){
                document.querySelector('div').textContent += text.charAt(i)
            }
            else{
                window.clearInterval(interval)
                document.querySelector('div').classList.remove("foo");
            }
            i++
            },20)
```